# How to test the text view value in a Recycler view list ? (with Espresso)

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-espresso

[image: Recycler view]

How to test the text in the middle is ON or OFF with Espresso?

Tried the below ways but didn't work.
Also facing this problem

`androidx.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: matches multiple views in the hierarchy.`. as there are multiple On/Off text visible with the same ID.

1 `onView(withText("Lights")).check(isLeftAlignedWith(withText("On")))`

2 `` onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(Adapter::class.java)), `is`("Lights"))).check( hasSibling(withText("On"))) ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists)

> Instead of using the onView() method, start your search with onData()
> and provide a matcher against the data that is backing the view you’d
> like to match. Espresso will do all the work of finding the row in the
> Adapter object and making the item visible in the viewport.